# Python : os.startswith function to get exact match

Tags: python

I am looking for info which starts with specific string using os.startswith() in python.

Here when i am looking for string "usb", i am also getting output with "usb4"

Eg output:-

```
builds/usb/test.txt
builds/usb/test2.txt
builds/usb4/file.txt
```

Script snippet :-

```
tarinfo.name.startswith("builds/usb")
```

I want to get the exact match. Here i am not interested in 'usb4'. How can we do that.. Please help.

Comment: `tarinfo.name.startswith("builds/usb/")`?

Comment: Why don't you try 'tarinfo.name.startswith("builds/usb/")' ?

Comment: You can put "build/usb/" , that will only consider usb and not usb4.

Comment: There is no `os.startswith`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use, forward slash in the end.

```
name.startswith("builds/usb/")
```

Comment: Actually, i am using os.path.join in my script as shown below : itarinfo.name.startswith(os.path.join("builds","usb")). To make my code as platform independent. Could you give answer by using os.path.join ? it would be helpful

Comment: use an empty string as the arg in the join method like this `os.path.join("builds","usb", "")`. It will add the trailing slash to the path. Output: `builds/usb/`